# Can't remove file from terminal folder

Tags: linux, filenames

I would like to remove the .xlsx file below in terminal folder. When I right click and do delete, it gives error: no such file. When I do 'ls' in command line it is not listed either. I refresh the terminal folder, it is still in there. why?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question marks might be representative of characters that your file manager is unable to display. If that is the only `.xlsx` file in the directory, try running the command `rm *.xlsx` in the terminal, from within the directory with the file in it.

Comment: This indicates a quite serious bug in whatever filemanager the user is using.  One that could potentially cause loss of data when deleting oddly named files.

Comment: Yes, it's indistinguishable from a valid filename which contains that sequence of `?`s. It would be much better to use the Unicode standard [replacement character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character): �

Comment: It looks as if the filenamanager is actually using literal `?` to delete the file, as if it was using the output of `ls`.

Comment: Consider `rm -i...` if you're not sure what will match.